# Overriding interface property type from exported type

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror, react-typescript

I have an interface type that extends some types, but I also want to "replace" one of the fields that comes in.

```
export interface Place
  extends Collections.Places.Entity<Timestamp, GeoPoint> {
  bounds: Bounds;
  center: Position;
  id: string;
}
```

The original type looks like this:

```
export interface Entity<TimestampType = Timestamp, GeoPointType = GeoPoint>
  extends Base<GeoPointType> {

  assignedPlaces?: AllThePlaces[];
  country: Country;
}
```

I want `assignedPlaces` to actually be a different type of NewPlaces[].

I tried something like:

```
export interface Place
  extends Pick<Collections.Places.Entity<Timestamp, GeoPoint>, Exclude<keyof Collections.Places.Entity<Timestamp, GeoPoint>, keyof Collections.Places.Entity['assignedPlaces']>> {
```

but this doesn't seem to be working. I can't figure out a combination that will let me overwrite.

```
Type 'AllThePlaces[] | undefined' is not assignable to type '(NewPlaces & { toTravel: string; })[] | undefined'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think this is the type you want:

> You don't need to supply generic type parameters when you are choosing the same ones as the defaults.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=30&ssc=2&pln=25&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhlADjAvDAygTwLYCMQA2AFAOQCCBBAKgBYCmACgXMHRCQJQDcAsAFChIsMMjRY8hUgDk6AdyYs2nXn35RMiOjArV6C1hFQx1mkADN4SFSa0z5zA0ZvmYI6xq0AhOBDoAeKgA+IwAlOlAAJwATPzA6ADc6CIAaGABXMABrMBBZMED3TRhPEAyowzQM7NywQq0AYVKwKAjMIyqcvLqYAHE6EAYQAEtm9qzO2rUPGEGIIagh8DHqrqmiqiHsNig4bFF08ZqVfijw5gitMF22REUYRspwhfBDAG9+GBg6AA9EEAjhNcILdWDMHGwYO8+J9Pj8-gCYCMoEkzHcAKLNeaYPwfGGfDZbaC7RBUaZoAnbYnJXF4voDYbNUlFNB0wZI6nQmHBH7IsDlYo+fyshlQJl0YJQvGfHxzADmcSi+jYAH4AFzaSi0RjgiAAbQAuiopTBQBkWph1Y0za0jTCAL64h18J38JEou5Kr7fXn8gDy2HmfgeBCei0gADolRBwxiFupUiQZUN5XRFTqSBLcUmU2nFBA1TA7FGDbb8GUIOqSuXbaxmkl1bN5mHbUMouroBERrKVC6+KdgOctIJoDBEOCG+CVGPFOHswqo1wYAB6JcwIjOCwiDgGmAAHwOpzMI1T-CAA)

```ts
interface Place extends Omit<Collections.Places.Entity, 'assignedPlaces'> {
  assignedPlaces?: NewPlaces[];
  bounds: Bounds;
  center: Position;
  id: string;
}

declare const place: Place;
place.assignedPlaces; // NewPlaces[] | undefined
```